# How to make bootstrap-tour work without using element?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tour

I am trying to implement Bootstrap tour in my application. It is working fine when i try to use id's and class name. But what i need is instead of using the id and class name, i need to use the text name where the step popover should be shown(position of popover)

Can someone help me to implement this Bootstrap tour without using any element like id or class and use a text name for the position of popover

```
`For example, in the below js fiddle i need to use the text names "Get Help","Place An Order","Announcements & Alerts" where the step popover should be shown.
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vL0gx5oq/11/